# Unexpected indent error in an if statement with multiple print lines

Tags: python, indentation

When I run my python script in python launcher, I get this error message:

```
, line 45
print([l[0] for l in e])
^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

This is the second of code that it is referring to:

```
flag = 0
num_comb = 1
comb = [c for i in range(len(menu)+1) for c in combinations(menu, i)]

for e in comb:
    if sum(l[1] for l in e) == maxSugar:
        print "The combination number " + str(num_comb) + " is:\n" 
        print([l[0] for l in e])
        print "\n\n\n"
        num_comb += 1 
        flag = 1

if flag == 0:
    print "there are no combinations of dishes for your sugar intake... Sorry! :D "
```

Any ideas as to why it is giving me an error? If I only include one print statement `print([l[0] for l in e])` the program runs fine! I am pretty new to python so not sure if I am allowed to include multiple `print` statements in an `if` block. I wouldn't see why not though.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? You seem to be calling both the 2.* and 3.* variants of the print command which might be part of your problem

Comment: You're mixing some python version there. `print()` and `print`. What Python version are you on?

Comment: Make sure that you are not mixing tabs and spaces in your first `if` block

Comment: Version is 3.3. I just drag the file.py into the python launcher. Is there a more professional and senseful way of launching a .py script?

Comment: @PaoloMoretti I checked my indentation and seems to be correct. I have indented the entire script with tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly this error comes from mixing tabs and spaces in your indentation. (According to [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) you shouldn't use tabs for indentation at all.) Apart from that I wonder if your code can run in python3 as you use version 2 style print statements in some cases.

Comment: so what do you suggest doing? And if you could briefly explain this difference between print and print().

Comment: I suggest to: 1) replace all tabs with 4 spaces and 2) write all print statements with brackets if you really use python 3 (i.e. print("something") instead of print "something")

Comment: Seems to work fine now! Thank you! So the only difference  in 3.* is really that print is a function but you can still concatenate with the `+` symbol etc? You only need to include the `()`. Also, do you prefer the older 2.7 python? Everyone kind of seemed against this new release

Comment: You're welcome :-) I'd be glad if you upvote/accept the answers that helped you. To python 3: I like it but some libraries that I use are not migrated to version 3 yet respectively I started the project with python 2 and do not want to invest the time migrating the whole thing.